A trail cam capture of an unknown bird in Tucson, AZ

My neighbor's trail cam in Tucson, AZ., caught this photo of an unknown bird in flight. Does anyone in this community have a suggestion as to what it could be? Thanks!

White tail tips and white/grey underside should be fairly easy to ID - most likely a common species, though you never know.

White-winged dove has the gray body and dark tail with white horizontal band and brown central feathers. It's feet are blurry but they do seem orange.
All about birds photo

Thank you BN! You nailed it!

You can accept the answer and thereby give BirdNerd extra points.
